# mvc ActionResult is not return to anotherView

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here I have two methods.

`Login` method

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginCrediential ObjCrendentials)
{
    if (x == true)
        return RedirectToAction("RoutingAction");
    else
        return View("Index");
}
```

`RoutingAction` method

```
public ActionResult RoutingAction()
{
    if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        return View("Admin/AdminHome/index");
    else if (User.IsInRole("Hr"))
        return View();
    else
        return View();
}
```

When my `if` condition Is `true` in the `Login` method, its navigating to `RoutingAction()` but throwing the following error

> Admin/AdminHome/index or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations

In url its showing as `http://localhost:3013/Home/RoutingAction`

Please help me how I can solve this issue.

Comment: The message is self explanatory - you do not have a view with that name!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, It's only going to search the Views folder of your controller (Home) and the Shared views.  However, you should be able to specify the full path to the View:

```
return View("~/Areas/Admin/Views/AdminHome/Index.cshtml");
```

But, if you want the url to reflect this location, then you probably need to have an AdminHome Controller and redirect to its index action.